# How to empty and dispose a heap (of boost library)?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dispose

I have a heap data structure from boost c++ library. It contains some pointers to another heap objects which itself points to some objects (i.e., I have a heap of heaps). When I call clear on the main heap, I makes the heap clear. But I want at the same time to delete the objects in it. Is there any way I can call (automatically) the destructor of the objects in the heap while cleaning it?

Thanks

```
void myClean(HeapType Heap)
{
    innerHeapType *inHeap = Heap->top();
    innerObjType  *tmp2;
    while (inHeap->size()>0)
    {
        tmp2 = curHeap->top();
        inHeap->pop();
        delete tmp2;
    }
    inHeap->clear();

    Heap->pop();
    delete inHeap;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried storing smart pointers in the main heap heap?  Then I think `clear()` will ensure destruction of the pointed-to heaps.  You may or may not want the non-main heap to use smart pointers depending on whether you want to destroy the data objects themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try them and make a feedback here...